# How do I display one same modal while clicking on two different images on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two images on my HTML page :

```
<a id="pop1" href="#"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>
```

and

```
<a id="pop2" href="#"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>
```

My modal code is below :

```
<div id="alarmModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Shutdown Machines with less than certain % CPU Utilization after N minutes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Please fill in the specifics below:</p>
                         <form id="alarm_form" action="/create_alarm/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                               <label for="period">Period of inactivity(in minutes):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="period" min="0" max="60" step="5" required>
                               <label for="cpu">CPU Utilization(in %):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="cpu" min="0" max="100" step="1" required>
            <br>
               <div id="alarmresult"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="optimize" type="submit" value="Optimize"></input>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How do I open this modal when both images are clicked on without using two separate javascript or jquery functions ? I mean only using one javascript or jquery function ?

Comment: $('#pop1, #pop2').on('click', e => alert("open modal here")); ?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML `class` attribute in the images.

**HTML**

```
<img class="loadmodal" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;">
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).on(click, 'img.loadmodal', function(){
    //Load the modal here
});
```

Comment: Adding an event listener on a class is easier in pure JavaScript. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$('#pop1, #pop2').click(function(){
    # open your modal here
})
```

or give a same `class` to your elements then:

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    # open your modal here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#pop1, #pop2').on('click',function(){
    $('#alarmModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use without javascript use data-toggle and data-target attributes.

```
 <a id="pop1" class="modalClass" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alarmModal"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>

<a id="pop2" class="modalClass"  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alarmModal"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>


<div id="alarmModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Shutdown Machines with less than certain % CPU Utilization after N minutes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Please fill in the specifics below:</p>
                         <form id="alarm_form" action="/create_alarm/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                               <label for="period">Period of inactivity(in minutes):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="period" min="0" max="60" step="5" required>
                               <label for="cpu">CPU Utilization(in %):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="cpu" min="0" max="100" step="1" required>
            <br>
               <div id="alarmresult"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="optimize" type="submit" value="Optimize"></input>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```